# How to show the wait cursor in UI while backgroud thread running

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, background

I need to show wait cursor when click the button to open next window. In my application after click the button loading values for next window in backgroud. It consume sometime to open next window. In between time i want to show the wait cursor in UI. So that i have used below code, but it shows the wait cursor after background process complete.

Please any one share your suggestion how to show the wait cursor while background thread running?

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

System.Threading.Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
            {
                this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                {
                    this.Cursor= Cursors.Wait;
                }));
            });
            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thread.IsBackground = false;
            thread.Start();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
}
```

Comment: Why do you start another thread? Why not just call `this.Cursor = Cursors.Wait` before starting the long-running task?

Comment: Besides that, `Thread.Sleep` blocks the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

If the user has to wait anyway, why would you use a background thread to load the window?

It is *possible* to do this:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait;
        await Task.Run(() => LoadWindow());
    }
    finally
    {
        Mouse.OverrideCursor = null;
    }
}
```

**But then the UI remains responsive** - which contradicts your use of the wait cursor.

I think it would be better to not have the background thread and just set the cursor before opening the window, then put it back after.

I use some helpers for this:

```
internal static void ShowWithWaitCursor(this Window view)
{
    WithWaitCursor(() => view.Show());
}

internal static void WithWaitCursor(Action action)
{
    Func<int> func = () => { action.Invoke(); return 0; };
    WithWaitCursor<int>(func);
}

internal static T WithWaitCursor<T>(Func<T> func)
{
    try
    {
        Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait;
        return func.Invoke();
    }
    finally
    {
        Mouse.OverrideCursor = null;
    }
}
```

Open a window:

```
Window win = new MyWindow();
win.DataContext = new MyViewModel(injectDependencies);
win.ShowWithWaitCursor();
```

Sometimes the ViewModel takes some time to load as well, so I use this:

```
Window win = new MyWindow();
win.DataContext = WindowHelpers.WithWaitCursor(() => new MyViewModel(injectDependencies));
win.ShowWithWaitCursor();
```